# error read-file in snort when reading back pcap file

Tags: ids, snort

I get this error when using `snort -r` to read a saved pcap file and apply snort rules on it.

```
ERROR : pfring daq does not support read-file
```

I am running snort in Security Onion

I tried many things:

```
sudo snort -i ens34 -c /etc/nsm/templates/snort/snort.conf -r pcap.pcap
```

Comment: Have you googled the error? Many others have posted the same problem.

Comment: Ironically, when searching for this error, this exact question is the second result on Google for me.

Comment: *"I tried many things: ...."* - you show exactly one thing and it is unclear what you've tried apart from that. And the example you showed  does not make sense since you given both an interface  (`-i ens34`) and file (`-r pcap.pcap`) as input. Please use only one input. Apart from that, it is unclear what your configuration contains since you only show the file name and not the file content.

Comment: @MechMK1: and the answer might be in the first result, so why even look at the second one :)

Comment: Of course I have googled the error, but there is no clear answer if u read these results, even though nothing worked for me , @SteffenUllrich it is the default configuration for snort , just installed the VM and run the snort with many pcaps, same result, I have also tried -r without the interface -i

Comment: @OSAMA: "... even though nothing worked for me..."* - you omit again what you've actually tried. It is totally useless to say that you've tried a lot or that nothing worked for you without saying what exactly you've tried.